# Change scrollbar color on hover CSS

Tags: c#, css

I'm trying to change the scrollbar color on hover in my application and for some reason, when i hover over it, it becomes red. Here's my code:

```
    .scroller {
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
overflow: auto;
```

}

```
    .scrooler:hover{  
      color: blue;
    }
```

With this code, all it does is as soon as I hover over my table, all the text becomes blue. i'm having a hard time getting only the scrollbar since I think it is directly within the table. Is there any way of targeting the scrollbar only?

Comment: does your table have the `scrooler` class?

Comment: Also, the scrollbar still becomes red on hover with this code, even though all the rest becomes blue

Comment: Yes it does, but the scroller is the table container. I'm trying to figure out how to target the scrollbar

Comment: I barely do any css but does `.scroller:hover > *{ color: black; }` do anything for you? This makes the children black

Comment: This puts the text all black and still keeps the scrollbar red :S

Comment: what type of element is scrollbar? maybe try this: `.scroller:hover > elementName` to target just the scrollbar. Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787178/applying-css-for-only-parent-but-not-to-children

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out. I can't target the scrollbar's element type since it is within the table and automatically generated imo.

Comment: If you open it in a browser and look in developer tools it will be an element, use that element

Comment: You can't' I've aleady inspected the whole page and tryed to target the scrollbar, it doesn't appear as an element, when I inspect the scrollbar, it shows me all the table and none of the table's children is the scrollbar

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was actually trying that but didn't put the scroller class in front haha

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is part of the table and color will be the text color (as always), but in css there is a special property for scrollbars:

```
scrollbar-base-color:YOURCOLOR;
```

just put this in your existing class