# How to color only the parent li and not all underlying li also?

Tags: css

I'm trying to only color the main li text Top 10, but it is coloring all child li items also at the moment. This what i have:

```
#main-menu .sidebar-menu li.orange-text a { color: #ff5923 !important; }
```

please check screenshot:
https://snipboard.io/TpueKj.jpg

Many thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787178/applying-css-for-only-parent-but-not-to-children

Comment: Read up about CSS selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors In this case you want to use the direct child selector which is >

Comment: Does this answer your question? [applying css for only parent but not to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787178/applying-css-for-only-parent-but-not-to-children)

Answer (score 1):

You need to select only those li that are direct children of ul elements that are direct children of the sidebar menu. You do this using the CSS selector >

```
#main-menu .sidebar-menu > ul > li.orange-text a { color: #ff5923 }
```

You are unlikely to need the !important, though I cannot be absolutely sure as I don't have access to all the styling of your site.

Comment: Thanks, important is needed, but this is still making all the ul and li in the orange text class orange?

Comment: Sorry, not sure if your comment is a question or a comment. Could you expand on the problem is it is still a problem? Also, you need to put your code direct into your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. this did the trick:
#main-menu .sidebar-menu .orange-text>a{
            color: #ff5923}

And i´m still not sure how to get the code nicely from chrome inspector to here?
Thanks

Comment: To pick up code from Chrome inspector you can copy it in the usual way. Then read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused. Your image doesn't show everything. But I'll try anyway.
I wouldn't use !important.
li .orange-text means the element where the class orange-text is a child of li. But from what I saw in your picture, it's a class applied to li.
If you want just the first one with the class orange Try:

```
#main-menu .sidebar-menu .orange-text:first-child a{
    color: #ff5923}
```

If you want all the ones with class orange and their decedents try:

```
#main-menu .sidebar-menu .orange-text a{
        color: #ff5923}
```

if you want to color only the a that is a direct child of the .orange-text li but not the grandsons, you may try:

```
#main-menu .sidebar-menu .orange-text>a{
            color: #ff5923}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, last one did the trick i needed.

Comment: Glad it worked. Maybe you can undo the downgrade vote before I get fired from stackoverflow.

Comment: I did not downgrade. Tried to upgrade but can't